# Is there a way to accurately plot a time series over an image using R or some other software

Tags: r, image, time-series

Is there a way to somehow plot time series data over an image with a line on it? If you specify where you want it to start and end?

Example Data

```
    Data 
2.064189
2.259854
2.483817
2.243919
2.259637
1.994976
1.898974
1.799953
2.153994
2.179374
2.637224
3.780604
4.52431
4.540029
3.968827
```

Example input:
[image: Example Input]

[image: Example Output]

This is probably the weirdest question I have ever asked, so I don't really expect an answer.

But if someone does know how to do this, is there a way to do it with a bent line?

Comment: You can plot images in the background and you could fiddle with the timeseries values to align them to the origin you want...

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the fig= values to align the plot with the image. The CRAN digitize package may also be of use.

```
library(jpeg)
set.seed(123)

plot(0:1, 0:1, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")

img <- readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package = "jpeg"))
rasterImage(img, 0, 0, 1, 1)

opar <- par(fig = c(.25, .75, .25, .75), new = TRUE, mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
plot(rnorm(10), type = "l", axes = FALSE, lwd = 3, col = "red")
par(opar)
```

[image: screenshot]